# servicestack app on web host

Tags: c#, servicestack, web-hosting

I have mvc integrated with serviceStack app and it works fine when it is not hosted. On the internet website crashes when I try to get data from the database through service. Do I need another connection to services or is there a problem somewhere else?

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information than what you've got above. How are you connecting to the Db? Show code for your AppHost.Configure method. Make sure you're web/app server network can access the DB you're connecting to. What is your setup like that is working locally? Are you connecting to MS SQL or Postgres or other? Are you using ServiceStack.OrmLite for database connection?

Comment: You at least could post some code and the exception.

Comment: I am using MongoDb and connecting through mongo repository library. Connection is in Service project where all the logic is. How can i make sure web server network can access the db?

Comment: Can you post some code please?